# Possibility of running Grails SDK in Windows 10 Bash Shell

Tags: bash, shell, grails, windows-10, sdkman

I'm having issues running the `Grails SDK` on `Windows 10 Bash Shell`. I've installed `SDKMan` to manage and install Grails.

```
| Grails Version: 3.1.12
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_101
me@WORKSTATION:~$
```

When I run `grails create-app name_here` or `grails run-app`, it just seems to timeout, go idle. It'll often seem stopped at

```
me@WORKSTATION:~$ cd mytestapp
| Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...
```

I was thinking of replacing my Cygwin environment with this.

**Update 1**

If I wait long enough, I get this error:

```
#
[thread 140206627161856 also had an error]# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#
#  Internal Error (safepoint.cpp:310), pid=119, tid=0x00007f8467770700
#  guarantee(PageArmed == 0) failed: invariant
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/dan/mytestapp/core or core.119
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/dan/mytestapp/hs_err_pid119.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```